# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLServiceFactory in soap webservice

Tags: rest, soap, cxf

while generating wsdl file giving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLServiceFactory giving , although have added cxf-rt-wsdl-3.3.4.jar dependency in classpath..
i had checked all the available answer on this but the error remains same trying all the solutions found.